# how to run powershell on remote windows get remote windows result instead of local

Tags: powershell

My local computer name is LOCAL-MACHINE,
And remote computer name is REMOTE-MACHINE.

I expect issue powershell cmdlets on local computer,
through Enter-PSSession connect to remote computer,
and excute hostname.exe on pssession of remote computer,
then exit.

I issue these command on local computer powershell ISE.

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Mypassword" -AsPlainText -Force

$cred=new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("domain\user",$password)

Enter-PSSession -ComputerName REMOTE-MACHINE -Port 5986  -Credential  $cred -UseSSL -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck)

hostname.exe

Exit-PSSession
```

I expect GET  resut：

```
REMOTE-MACHINE
```

But I get this result(local computer name)：

```
 LOCAL-MACHINE
```

What can I do？

Comment: Do you actually see the console prompt changed to `[REMOTE-MACHINE]: PS C:\..` ? if not you are not connected... also are you run it all at once? or line by line?

Comment: Wait until Enter-PSSession has been executed, before executing `hostname.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because Enter-PSSession does not work in a script. Use [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6) instead:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "Mypassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred=new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("domain\user",$password)

Invoke-Command -ComputerName REMOTE-MACHINE -Port 5986  -Credential  $cred -UseSSL -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck) -scriptblock {

    hostname.exe
}
```